# Spring4 MVC keep session alive forever

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-4

I have a scenario where session is getting expired after some time of inactivity, But i need to keep Spring 4 MVC keep session alive forever.
Below is my Spring Initializer class,

'''public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
            "SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

}
```

}'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -1 in  tag because -1 is for session never expires.

Web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: i am using Spring4 MVC So i do NOT have web.xml in my project. So where can i set ?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/nlpraveennl/stackoverflow-answer-reference/tree/master/springsecurity-auth-success-handler-javaconfig